# How can I protect my question from more answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

My question on Stack Exchange already has a fantastic answer. Now everyone, who just knows a little about the question, is trying to answer with his fuzzy logic which rushes on the post.

Can this thing stopable from further answering a question when there are great answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in answer to your question about how you can lock it - only Moderators can. So you'd have to flag the question and request a moderator lock it.

**However.** It is very unlikely that they will though. Locking is really only used for questions that are historically useful to the site, but that aren't really on-topic any longer. Or they're locked because there is an ongoing content dispute about the contents. But those are temporary.

*What is more likely* (although still not especially probably) is that a moderator can '**Protect**' the question. This stops people with no reputation on the site from leaving answers. Mostly this is used when a question becomes a Hot Question and users from all over the network / social media / sharing sites etc discover the question and come in to leave spam answers, or 'Me Too!' answers. It doesn't prevent established users from leaving answers though.

It's unlikely a mod will lock or protect a question just because the answer it has is already sufficient though.

Comment: Your redundant statement about content dispute about the contents is redundant.

Comment: In other words, if you want to get your question locked, you need to engage in a content dispute with someone else.

Answer (score 13):

No. Technologies, languages and opinions can evolve in time. Something that is the best possible answer *now*, is considered inaccurate, outdated and useless in a few years.

If it attracts low-quality answers from < 10 rep users, the question might be protected. In all other cases: Why stop users from posting an answer and risk you will never end up with an even better answer?

Besides that, community wikis aren't yours, they belong to the community. And even if it would belong to you, it seems a bad idea to stop users from contributing.

Comment: @Robert it wasn't advice really. The contrary. It was to let OP know that that option is a bad one. If you don't want it there, it's okay to me.